# Update column in ORACLE SQL with the difference between data from 2 other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `LEAVE_DETAILS` table which looks like this -

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 EMPLOYEEID                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
 LEAVESTARTDATE                                     DATE
 LEAVEENDDATE                                       DATE
 LEAVETYPE                                          VARCHAR2(3)
 REASON                                             VARCHAR2(50)
 REPORTINGDATE                                      DATE
 LEAVES_EXPENDED                                    NUMBER(2)
```

I want the `LEAVES_EXPENDED` column to automatically update the number of leaves taken whenever new data is inserted.

`LEAVES _EXPENDED` would be calculated using `trunc(LEAVEENDDATE) - LEAVESTARTDATE`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you looking for a virtual column, or a trigger? Or just to do it manually on insert? (Or even calculate it when queried, with a view?) Does the assignment specify the approach you need?

Comment: Approach isn't specified. Just need a working solution.

Comment: Why do you want to store that information at all? That can easily be calculated in a view without any performance drawbacks

Comment: Well, have you been taught about triggers or virtual columns? Have you tried either approach?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view and have it calculate the data when queried